# Visual Studio for Mac 2017 only allows publish to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac

Why does VS2017 for Mac only allow you to publish a .net core web api to Azure.  There is no other option.  Is it because I'm using the community edition?  If there is no other option beside Azure, how then do I publish?

Comment: "There is no other option." What are the options you are looking for?

Comment: @LexLi there use to be a publish to file, ftp, etc in other version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Currently Visual Studio for Mac only supports publishing to Azure for ASP.NET Core projects. This is independent of the edition you are using. Your best bet is to use Visual Studio on Windows if you need to support publishing to file or FTP.

Comment: @Machavity I edited the question to remove my ramblings about licensing.

Answer (score 1):

Found this little jewel that will answer all your .net core questions as well as how to publish in IIS:  [Thank you Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS#'Running'IIS)

But basically I ran this command to publish (win7-x64 is an RID for Windows 2008R2):

`dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x64 -f netcoreapp2.0`